How can I render a html component in a vue app using routing?
I have a uni assignment with really vague instructions. I basically need to take a html file from an older project version, move the form within the file to a vue component, render the html file and the vue component within it. I used routing for all my links because it's easier, but now I can't figure out how to get the html to render.
Their instructions are add <div id="vue-form-container">
and then
<script>
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent.vue'; // Adjust path as needed
const app = createApp(ExampleComponent);
app.mount('#vue-form-container');
</script>

i already using app.mount(#app) instead of app.mount('#vue-form-container'); (and changing the div id) which didn't work.
is this even possible? i'll put my index.js and main.js code in, the contact html and vue components are very basic so their content doesn't really matter. appreciate any help.
index.js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
// Other component imports
import ContactPage from '../src/components/ContactPage.vue';


const routes = [
    // Other paths, not relevant
    { path: '/contact', component: Contact},
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;

main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from '../router';


// Create Vue Application
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');


App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header />
    <router-view />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';
import Home from './components/HomePage.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
    Home
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@import './styles/styles.css';
</style>

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Whispering Leaves</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="./main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>TEST HTML IS RENDERING</h1>
    <div id="app">
        <contact-form></contact-form>
    </div> <!-- Vue app mounts here -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
    <script>
      import { createApp } from 'vue';
      import App from './App.vue'; // Adjust path as needed
      const app = createApp(App);
      app.mount('#app');
      </script>
      
  </body>

</html>


Don't change anything and just put <router-view></router-view> in your ExampleComponent.vue and tell me what does it show ?

Still only shows the vue elements. I have <router-view></router-view> in App.vue, I'll add it to the original post, but I added <router-view></router-view> to both App.vue and ContactPage.vue and html still doesn't render.

Can you please include the index.html code you use because it's confusing me seeing inline script and main.js

Yep for sure, sorry about that

ok so first of all remove the 
Done, didn't fix it unfortunately

does it show any console errors ? what does it show exactly ? also i think the <router-view></router-view> should be in app.vue sorry

That's half the problem, no related console errors. I can't find anything in the inspect element that has anything to do with the html file, it doesn't seem to even know it exists.

@niko The question lacks clear problem statement. It's evident this is the consequence of "vague instructions", but it's unclear what's your current attempt and what you want to achieve in the end. Why is "createApp(App)" both in index.html and main.js? It cannot work in index.html, the script is not valid. Where is index.js used? What is the setup? Vite? The question says nothing about this, while it's very relevant. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Providing a workable demo will help you to get a workable fix.
